# JQuery template: async template loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates

Can I use jquery template without having to have all the templates (text/x-jquery-tmpl) in the page but loaded 'on demand' via ajax?

I'm trying with a custom tag, but I do not have the desired results:

```
function loadTemplate(template, data){

                var html;

                $.ajax({
                    url: "/widgets/"+template,
                    async : false,
                    success: function(result){
                        html = $(result).tmpl(data).html();

                    }
                });


                return html;
            }

function extendTmpl() {


        $.extend(jQuery.tmpl.tag, {
            'atmpl': {
                _default: { $1: "null", $2: "null" },
                open: '_=_.concat(loadTemplate($1, $2));'
            },
        });
```

}

Comment: have you tried Dynamic switching of templates, using `.template()` to obtain compiled template.

Comment: I can not use Dynamic switching models because there is still no template. It's a nested template but the template is not present in page, is in a different file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation $(element).tmpl() takes the first element in the matched set and renders **its content**, i.e:

```
$('<span>hello</span>').tmpl() // => "hello"
```

The result is simply a text node without the span. 
On the opposite:

```
$.tmpl('<span>hello</span>') // => "<span>​hello​</span>​"
```

You can either use this latter syntax or wrap your result in an empty `<div>` before processing: `$(<div>).append(result).tmpl(...)`